# JS: .then is not a function when trying to get contents of a promise

Tags: javascript

```
var rbx = require('roblox-js');

rbx.login('INF_BOT', '$$$')
.then(function (info) {
 console.log('Logged in with ID ' + info.userId);
 rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1)
.then(function (players) {
  for( var Plr in players) {
    console.log(Plr)
  }
})
.catch(function (err){
  console.error(err.stack);
})
})
   .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
});
```

I keep getting the output: http://prntscr.com/e0upfl

Here is the getPlayers.js: http://pastebin.com/wD6bjStc

I have no clue why .then is throwing the error, basically the getPlayers returns and object, within that object there is a promise and status, within the promis there is an object... Atleast that is what the API is showing me.

Basically I am running a function called getPlayers() but it returns an object, and in that object is a Promise, and a function. I need to get the Promise and .then it...

Comment: where is `getPlayers` defined? does it return a promise?

Comment: The solution is pretty simple if its a custom function that you wrote. Simply wrap the return value in Promise.resolve(<return value>) and return it.
Eg: return Promise..resolve('thisIsTheValueToReturn') and that function becomes thenable.

Comment: Also rember that in order to not break the promise chain you must always return the promise in .then().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm bored so I decided to help you out and navigate the [roblox-js lib](https://github.com/sentanos/roblox-js) for you.

The code [here](https://github.com/sentanos/roblox-js/blob/3f547e1ac109742dee55de30eab60c4731968130/lib/getPlayers.js#L162-L190) is what is returned from the `getPlayers` function. Looks like you need to look for `getPlayers().promise.then` rather than just `getPlayers().then` as the function doesn't return just the promise. It returns an object with a property called `promise` (what you're looking for I presume) and a `getStatus` function.

```
var rbx = require('roblox-js');

rbx.login('INF_BOT', '$$$')
  .then(function (info) {
    console.log('Logged in with ID ' + info.userId);
    rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1).promise // <-------------------------------
      .then(function (players) {
        for (var Plr in players) {
          console.log(Plr);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
      })
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  });
```

Comment: +1, this corresponds quite well with what the OP said: "but it returns an object, and in that object is a Promise"